# 403 CSRF verification failed Django when refresh url?

Tags: python, django

I have create a view that takes in a post request from my /login route, but after accepting the login post request and redirecting to /, when the user refresh the browser, I get a 403 CSRF failure code.

How can i optimize my code so that if the user refreshes the browser it doesn't prompt the error?

view

```py
def index(request):
    username = password = '' 

    if request.method == 'POST':
        HttpReferrer = request.session.get('HttpReferrer')
        if  HttpReferrer == '/login':
            username = request.POST['username'].lower().strip()
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None and user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return index_(request)
            else:
                err = {"err_login": {"code": 404, "message": "The username and password combination do not match our records. Please double-check and try again."}}
                return render(request, 'auth/auth.html', err)
```

Comment: It seems my answer didn't help.

If you found a solution you might answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to post to an index page?

It is the login page (the login view) , that is supposed to handle the login, right?

If the login view handles login, then just get the user in your index view with `user = request.user`

you shouldn't have to reauthenticate in the index view.

If on the other hand the index view is your login view, then why do you check the referer?